# Setting pixel of image 1 to transparent to show image behind image 1

Tags: c#, asp.net

The program that I am working on requires that I layer two images on top of each other (z indexes will be 1 number apart). The top layer is a black image(png) and the bottom layer is a normal image that you would pull from google. Let's say I pull a set of pixels from a database that had been previously entered(100 pixels for example); I want those 100 pixels to turn transparent. My current code is responding by changing the pixel to plain white. Anyone have any suggestions?

This code snippet represents specific pixels being pulled from a database.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand sqlRead = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PIXEL", con);
        List<int> pixelIds = new List<int>();

        using (SqlDataReader read = sqlRead.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                int pixel = Convert.ToInt32(read[0]);
                pixelIds.Add(pixel);
                int yaxis = Convert.ToInt32(pixel) / 1000;
                int xaxis = Convert.ToInt32(pixel) % 1000;
                image1.SetPixel(xaxis, yaxis, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The essential part of the code is where you save the image. Are you sure you're saving a PNG with transparency?

Comment: And you might want to call one of the MakeTransparent() methods of the bitmap (possibly rather the one with the Color argument).

Comment: @Alexander Yes I'm very sure.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've heard of the MakeTransparent() method but I'm not too sure as to how I would implement that method in place of "Color.Transparent". Would you be able to point me in the right direction or link something that you know would be a good reference?

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - note that this adds an alpha channel which might yet be missing in your image.

Comment: Solved. What I had to do was change the `Color.Transparent` to `Color.Brown` then wrote `image1.MakeTransparent(Color.Brown)` below that which worked perfectly. Thank you all for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. What I had to do was change the `Color.Transparent` to `Color.Brown` then wrote `image1.MakeTransparent(Color.Brown)` below that which worked perfectly. Thank you all for the responses.